# Is "there" omittable in this kind of sentence, "Have you ever wondered how many atoms are in a drop of water"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

This [post](https://www.thoughtco.com/atoms-in-a-drop-of-water-609425) says

> Have you ever wondered how many atoms are in a drop of water or how many molecules are in a single droplet?

If I rewrite this as

Have you ever wondered how many atoms **there** are in a drop of water ...

Is this still idiomatic? in other words, are both with and without "there" idiomatic?

Comment: @BillJ Thanks for your reminder. updated.

Comment: I would not use it. It just confuses things.

Answer (score 2):

> X atoms are in a drop of water

is idiomatic as is

> There are X atoms in a drop of water.

I suspect that "there are" is likely to be more common, at least in the U.S. because "it is" and "there are" are ubiquitous constructions there. Stylistically, I prefer "X atoms are" as more concise, but that is mere opinion.

Because both declarative sentences are idiomatic so are the questions formed from them.

> How many atoms are in a drop of water?

or

> How many atoms are there in a drop of water?